# react navigation send me this error: the component for route router must be a react component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to create navigation for my react native app, but it shows me this error. I don't know how to fix it. At the bottom I have my JS files:

I tried all the codes, for example, I write export className and import {className}

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Login from './screens/Login'
import Signup from './screens/Signup'
import Home from './screens/home'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppRoot />
    )
  }
}
const Container = createAppContainer({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Signup: { screen: Signup },

  Home: { screen: Home },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
})
const AppRoot = createStackNavigator(Container)
```

**Login.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> login </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Signup extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Signup </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**home.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Home </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Can help you: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use react-navigation functions in wrong order. First you have to create stack navigator and then create app container with it:

```js
const Container = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Signup: { screen: Signup },

  Home: { screen: Home },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login'
})
const AppRoot = createAppContainer(Container)
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

remove import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack' and use 
import { createAppContainer,createStackNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';

Comment: I tried this, but it shows me 'createStackNavigator has been moved in react -navigation-stack'

Comment: Have you tried react-native-link to link your dependency to your project?

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './screens/Login'
import Signup from './screens/Signup'
import Home from './screens/home'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppRoot />
    )
  }
}
let RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  Signup: Signup,
  Home: Home,
})
const AppRoot = createAppContainer(RootStack)
```

Now Navigation props are present across all your screens Login,Signup,Home. To navigate from Login to home for example

Login.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

    export default class Login extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                    <Text> Home </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: I tried this, but it shows me 'createStackNavigator has been moved in react -navigation-stack'

Comment: ok then npm install react-navigation-stack and import {createStackNavigator} from react-navigation-stack

Comment: Problem with your code is that first you have to make a rootstack and then wrap it within appcontainer where as you did the other way around. It should work now.

Comment: Before that I imported from react native stack

Comment: are you using react-navigation or react-native-navigation?. Use react navigation v4.0 and import from react-navigation-stack

Comment: I used react navigation and I imported from react navigation stack when I said imported from react  native stack I wrote wrong